# omitting relative pronoun

Tags: grammar

"The man who lives in the house likes watching TV all day." when omitting "who", should it be "The man in the house likes watching TV all day" or "The man being in the house likes watching TV all day? Thanks

Comment: You can't omit a relative pronoun that is the subject, like _who_ in _who lives in the house._ You can only omit non-subject relative pronouns. To get _the man in the house_ you have to do _to be_-deletion (which won't work with _who lives_, only with _who is_). To get _the man living in the house_ you have to change the tensed relative clause to an untensed gerund clause, which can delete subjects. Neither of these is a matter of "omitting relative pronoun", but of a completely different phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

"The man in the house likes watching TV all day" or "The man LIVING in the house loves watching TV all day".